# TEXT() equivalent for strings in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, TEXT() can format numbers but I cannot find one for strings.

For example,

> TEXT(012345678,"00-000-0000")

formats the number into

> 01-234-5678

I want to do a similar thing but with strings, like:

> AABCDEEEF to AA-BCD-EEEF

I guess using several functions can yield the same result but I want to know if there is a simple method, like TEXT().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to convert `AABCDEEEF` to `AA-BCD-EEEF`.

How about this sample formula?

#### Sample formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A5,"(.{2})(.{3})(.{4})","$1-$2-$3"))
```

- In this case, I used `REGEXREPLACE`.
- When you want to use only one cell, please use `REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(.{2})(.{3})(.{4})","$1-$2-$3")`

#### Result:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)